# Fatal error: SourceGuardian Loader - For security reasons this protected script cannot run in the current PHP environment

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

When i install Zephyr theme and active it in wordpress localhost (Wamp server),
show me this error:

wordpress version:6.1.1
wamp server version:3.3.0
php version:8.2.0
apache version:2.4.54.2

```
**atal error: SourceGuardian Loader - For security reasons this protected script cannot run in the current PHP environment. Please contact the author of the script regarding this problem. Error code [16] in C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-content\themes\Zephyr\abzarwp\abzarwp-v13.php on line 2**
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0042  364232  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0055  364536  require( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-blog-header.php )    ...\index.php:17
3   0.0062  365112  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-load.php )  ...\wp-blog-header.php:13
4   0.0070  365664  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-config.php )    ...\wp-load.php:50
5   0.0074  374552  require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-settings.php )  ...\wp-config.php:96
6   0.3808  4399216 include( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-content\themes\Zephyr\functions.php )    ...\wp-settings.php:585
7   0.3834  4410752 require_once( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-content\themes\Zephyr\abzarwp\abzarwp.php ) ...\functions.php:44
8   0.3836  4411568 require( 'C:\wamp64\www\learn-wordpress\wp-content\themes\Zephyr\abzarwp\abzarwp-v13.php )  ...\abzarwp.php:19
9   0.3836  4411568 sg_load( $encoded = '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'... )
```

Comment: Thank your Anti-virus and remove the theme. `$encoded = '65A85B6289B04209AAQAAAAXAAAABHAAA[...]` is a clear combat indiciator of malicious content

Comment: are you sure?beacuse in my Educational video use this theme But there was no problem

Comment: Ok, interestingly, it appears they're utilising SourceGuardian which actually stores OP Codes in an encrypted string which later is passed to the `sg_load` extension function inside of SourceGaurdian to execute. This prevents the modification and view of the code. It also defines usecases of the code (to DNS/MAC/IP/Time). I'm unsure why a open-source project would contain this if not to hide something they do not want to be seen and given the indication of potential security issues, I would not ignore it and seek a better educational video.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.sourceguardian.com/fc-i-ve-got-an-error-cat-14.html

Usually, this error means you need to disable xdebug PHP extension since it is disallowed and can't be used along with SourceGuardian encoded files in production.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34928953)